# Почему не выполняется viewDidAppear?

Tags: swift

Есть три viewController scene: protected, login, registration. При старте запускается protected и если пользователь не залогинен - идет переход на login view.
ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self);
}
}
```

Но после загрузки protected ничего не происходит. Даже точки остановки ставил на viewDidAppear и на viewDidLoad, нигде не остановилась программа. 
identifier укззан. Да, знаю, что здесь нет логики касательно авторизации, проверки логина там. Но эта функция даже без всяких условий не работает.

Comment: Уверен, что у вас ошибка где-то до этого. Ибо если бы все стартовало с вашего ViewController, то такой бы код работал. (но я бы советовал добавить вызов super.viewDidApper и убрать ";" после performSegue)
Как вы попадаете на этот Controller?

Comment: @OlegB Вряд ли ошибка до этого, так как это первые строчки которые я написал в этом проекте. super.viewDidApper() в viewDidLoad() добавить? На controller [через entry point](https://imgur.com/a/GOUcKUr) попадаю.

Comment: проверьте, какой класс указан в Identity Inspector в Storyboard. Должен быть ваш.
Переименуйте ViewController в что-то более наглядное. Так будет проще найти ошибку. Для дебага достаточно хотя бы StartViewController.

Comment: @OlegB заработало! Спасибо. Не то имя было. А как лучше скрыть контент с protected слоя до проверки авторизации? Пока вижу один вариант: контент будет закрывать полностью белая картинка, и если авторизация прошла - то у неё альфа-канал становится - 0. Норм решение? Проблема в том,  что если пользователь не авторизирован, то protected view все равно видно при старте.

Comment: Что значит protected слой?
Вы используете этот ViewController только для того, чтобы решить авторизован пользователь или нет, а потом переходите на другой?

Comment: @OlegB ну там весь контент будет который доступен только авторизованным пользователям. По [гайду](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5pzlbBnfYg) делаю.

Comment: Я мельком пробежался по вашему гайду. Советую вам искать другие гайды...

Comment: @OlegB а как бы вы эту логику организовали бы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему мы выяснили (не верно указанный класс в Storyboard).

Если вы хотите показывать экраны авторизации, если пользователь не авторизован, и основной контент, если авторизован, то можно добавить эту проверку в `AppDelegate` и уже внутри него решать какой контроллер показать в первую очередь.

Пример:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let storyboardName: String
        if userAuthorized() { //здесь любая ваша проверка
            storyboardName = "Main"
        } else {
            storyboardName = "Authorization"
        }
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        return true
    }

    func userAuthorized() -> Bool {
        //это лишь пример. В реальности, конечно, здесь все может быть сложнее, и хранить токен в UserDefaults не стоит
        if let token = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "MyTokenKey") as? String {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: То-есть для viewController для авторизации, и для viewController, который доступен только авторизованным пользователям лучше создавать разные storyboard?

Comment: @hohfiofi если вы используете ViewController из Storyboard, то, конечно, лучше использовать несколько Storyboard. Каждый из которых описывает свой сценарий.

Comment: Вы написали, что хранить токен в UserDefaults не стоит. И password с email там тоже не нужно хранить? Почему? iOS это же очень безопасная ОС.

Comment: @hohfiofi для этого лучше использовать Keychain.
Почитать про него можете тут https://habr.com/ru/post/351116/ .

Comment: Еще вопрос. При таком способе перехода, переход на "Main" происходит два раза. Как я понял из-за того, что в настройках main interface указан  Main.storyboard. Если поменять на launchscreen.storyboard, то один раз выполняется переход. Но ведь это не правильно? В main interface должен быть не launchscreen.storyboard(для этого есть отдельная настройка), а действительно главный интерфейс. Проверял я это поставив print() во viewDidAppear и во viewDidLoad в Main.storyboard.

Comment: @hohfiofi просто отчистите Main interface поле, т.е. сделайте его пустым.
Либо можете в info.plist удалить это поле. В результате все должно работать как ожидаете (без двойного перехода).